# Extra spacing in Firefox only but not showing in inspector

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox

Am working on a site and Firefox is showing extra space around the nav bar. However I can't see any issues in the inspector (margins, padding or similar) and it only appears in FF. It's fine in IE, Chrome & Safari.

I've also looked for missing end tags which might be causing quirks modes tricks, but can't see any issues.

I just can't see what's causing the issue. Please help!

Here's the test site:
http://hhl.webassemble.net/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add on .inset-width  rule overflow:hidden and everything gonna be alright)))).